# SQL INNER JOIN doesnt return me what i need

Tags: mysql, sql

```
$rs25 = $connector->query("
    SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT content.*,topics.title AS topi2 FROM content 
      INNER JOIN topics 
      ON topics.id=content.topic) a
    WHERE a.user='$sf' ORDER BY a.date DESC");
```

I think the problem is in this syntax. What i want to do is SELECT `topics.title` WHERE `content.topic=topics.id` and order it by `content.date (DATETIME)` DESC
Or maybe i don't use the right join? Thank you.

Comment: Why do you have the derived table? And what do you mean with "doesnt return me what i need"? How are we supposed to know what you need and what is returned?

Comment: ok. i need it to return me for every `content.topic` an `topics.title` . it returns me everytime the same `topics.title`.

Answer (score 0):

There is really no need for the sub-query you have in your question just simply do as follows:

```
SELECT content.*,topics.title AS topi2 
FROM content  INNER JOIN topics 
ON topics.id = content.topic
WHERE content.user='$sf' 
ORDER BY content.date DESC
```

Comment: maybe ORDER BY content.date DESC?